# initialize TableViewController with initWithStyle from TabBarController in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, iphone, initwithstyle

I have a TabBarController in Interface Builder.
I assigned a subclassed UITableViewController as ViewController of Tab 2, works fine.

But I would like to set the style of the UITableViewController's TableView to UITableViewStyleGrouped.
The only way to do this is apparently(?) to call UITableViewController:initWithStyle:

So my question is: How can I 
a) either tell interface builder to initialize the viewcontroller with initWithStyle or
b) use some other way to achieve this? I tried already to override initWithStyle in the ViewController, but apparently it is not called when the tabbarcontroller shows the viewcontroller (it is however called when initializing the viewcontroller programmatically).

I like the way I can control the tab bar controller and its viewcontrollers from IB and wouldn't want to call the viewcontroller programmatically unless there is no other way.

As always, thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution: Adding a nib file to the view controller:

- Make sure the viewcontroller within the tabbarcontroller is of (sub-)class TableViewController
- Drag a TableView    from the Library below the TableViewController
- IB sets delegate and datasource, and the style is changeable in the TableView

Good luck to anyone else having this problem!